# windows phone wireless scans

Tags: wifi, windows-phone

I try to retrieve how to scan wireless networks on the windows phone. I found only examples about working with sockets in msdn documentation. Is possible get information about strength of signal (RSSI value in dB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information on the signal strength of connected networks is not made available to apps; Instead you can find out from the [`Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) if the network is available, whether it is a WiFi network, as well as information on the cellular network (name, whether it is data enabled, whether roaming is allowed), but not strength nor details of disconnected networks.

The closest you can get is to retrieve the available bandwidth (from [`Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), as that can have a bearing on signal strength (but it cannot be guaranteed to be a proportional relationship)